# Memory used to store dictionary python vs java

Tags: java, python, performance, hash

I want to build a list/array containing dictionaries. Each dictionary contains an integer as key and a (potentially really long) int array. I have implemented this on `python` using `numpy` as follows:

```
def get_dicts(dict_names):

    dictionaries = [None]*len(dict_names)
    k = 0
    my_dict = {}
    for i in dict_names:
        local_dict = my_dict.copy()
        with open(i, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                v = np.fromstring(line, dtype=int, sep=' ')
                local_dict[v[0]] = v[1:]

        dictionaries[k] = local_dict
        k += 1
        print "Dictionary %s extracted" % i
    return dictionaries

def main():
     dict_names = [str(i) + "_tweet_mapping" for i in range(1, 45)]
     dictionaries = get_dicts(dict_names)
```

The runtime is ok: 90 seconds. However, python is too slow later on in my problem and I am porting everything to java. In java, building these dictionaries in a `ListArray` of `HashMaps` takes a lot of memory having even problems with the `heap`. The runtime is also much slower. My java implementation is as follows:

```
private ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer, Integer[]>> get_dicts(String [] dictionary_files) {

    ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer, Integer []>>  my_dictionaries = new ArrayList<Hashtable<Integer,Integer []>>(dictionary_files.length);
    for (int i=0; i<dictionary_files.length; i++) {
         my_dictionaries.add(get_one_dict(dictionary_files[i]));
    }
    return my_dictionaries;

}

private Hashtable<Integer, Integer []> get_one_dict(String dictionary_file){

    Hashtable<Integer, Integer []> my_dictionary = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer[]>();
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictionary_file));
        try{
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
                String [] words = s.split(" ");
                int n_tweets = words.length-1;
                Integer [] int_line = new Integer[n_tweets];
                int key_word = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
                for (int j=0; j<n_tweets; j++){
                    int_line[j] = Integer.parseInt(words[j+1]);

                }

                my_dictionary.put(key_word, int_line);

            }
        }finally{
            br.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Dictionary " + dictionary_file +" extracted");
    return my_dictionary;
}
```

Why is there this huge difference in performance both in time and memory. What can I do to reduce memory consumption in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wrapper type `Integer` instead of an `int`. For the map key, you have no choice, but for the array you do.

Using `Map<Integer, int[]>` will reduce the memory consumption per element from 4 + 16 bytes to 4 bytes.(*)

---

You should also forget `Hashtable` and use `HashMap` instead. The former is synchronized, which you don't need. But this should not be a big issue.

I guess the slowdown came mostly from the needless memory allocation.

---

(*) 4 (or 8 on a 64-bit JVM without compressed OOPS) for the reference and 16 for the object (that's the minimum size).

Comment: Thank you! I misread the documentation and thought everything should be Integer and that is why I changed my first implementation with int (that obviously did not run). About the ``HashMap`` I actually tried with both. Apparently I copied paste my last "Experiment" with ``Hashtable`` here. Now it fits in memory and goes much faster.